# Appending Item to DynamoDB list atomically

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a field which is a list of Dictionaries.

```
{
 "messages": [item1, item2....]
}
```

Multiple hosts will be appending items to that list.

Is there any consideration to take into account to ensure that atomic appends?

Answer (score 3):

Use `list_append()` and `if_not_exists()` together to append to a potentially non-existent list column:

```
var params = {
  TableName: "yourTableName",
  Key: { hash: "someId" },
  UpdateExpression: "set #messages = list_append(if_not_exists(#messages, :empty_list), :message)",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    "#messages": "messages"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":message": [{ "id": "1","foo": "bar" }],
    ":empty_list": []
  }
};
```